# Git Pull Remote Branch using Shallow Clone

Tags: git, version-control, shallow-clone

I have done the git `shallow clone`. Since one of the git projects where I work is around more than 2Gb and I don't have to pull every branch and old data.

I pretty much clone the `master` branch only and then updated git config to pull my branches from the remote even if they are created in different machines

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://repo.com/_git/Project
    fetch = +refs/heads/users/abc/*:refs/remotes/origin/users/abc/*  
    //I changed above one to pull all my branches
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Cool thing is, now I will be able to pull my branches along with master which is pretty much good for 99%. Sometimes I want to pull explicitly another user branch `users/xyz/TestBranch`.

How do I modify git config to pull that. Without updating `git config` to pull all branches (full copy), it throws `error: pathspec 'users/xyz/TestBranch' did not match any file(s) known to git`